# generic functor class in java

Tags: java, generics, functor

I'd like to have functor class like this:

```
public class Functor<T, R> { 
    public R invoke(T a) { ... }
}
```

And another class for the 2 arguments:

```
public class Functor<T1, T2, R> { 
    public R invoke(T1 a, T2 b) { ... }
}
```

And so on.

In C# i can write:

```
class Functor<T> { ... }
class Functor<T1, T2> { ... }
```

But in Java it would be an error:

```
The type Functor is already defined
```

What are best practices for multi-arguments generic classes in java?

Comment: Not an answer to your question - but are you aware of libraries such as http://functionaljava.org/ which would provide you with an out of the box set of functors plus a rich library built around them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because generics are implemented in Java by erasing the type information (in `class C<T>`, `T` goes away in the compiled .class file) there is no way for the compiler to know what class you are talking about at runtime.

If you define `F<T1>` and `F<T1,T2>` and load them both, some class `C`, could not identify the one it wanted to use.

This is the long way around saying, I don't think you can do that in Java. :\

What you might want to do is simply have a single argument functor `F<T>` and let `T` be the object, a `Pair<T1, T2>` object, a `ThreeTuple<T1, T2, T3>` etc. Scala does this.

Comment: thanks! and what best practice for the multi-arguments generic classes in java?

Comment: I just edited the answer to include it. In short in F<T> T becomes an argument type that holds 1 or 2 or 3 ... N types for your inputs. Eg, F<ThreeTuple<T1, T2, T3>>.

Comment: @sam - Formatting tip: you can use backticks (\`) to enclose inline code formatting so you don't have to worry about using &lt; etc. That works in both posts and comments. Oh and +1

Comment: Instead of having multiple tuple classes, you can also have multiple functor classes, eg, `F0<R>`, `F1<A, R>`, `F2<A, B, R>`, etc. You can also have a more generic superclass `F<R>` with `R invoke(Object... args)` that is redirected to the specific invoke methods of the subclasses.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting tips. Much appreciated, as are the edits. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you call it a functor? If you check out the definition of functor in wikipedia, you'll see this is a wrong term.

In Scala this is called Function; and due to the specifics of jvm and bytecode, there are many versions, depending on arity: `Function0<Res>, Function1<T1, Res>, Function2<T1,T2, Res>`, etc, up to `Function22`.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question - should be a comment.